# How to change months label in owl date time picker?

Tags: angular

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) 
Im working with ng-date-time-picker and idk how is possible change months label. 
Im using some providers to change the labels of all buttons but i cant change months names.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './custom-datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-datepicker.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: DateTimeAdapter, useClass: MomentDateTimeAdapter, deps: [OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE] },
    { provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_MOMENT_DATE_TIME_FORMATS },
    { provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: DefaultIntl },
  ],
})
```

[**this is what i want to change**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpsIU.png)

Comment: using `{provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr'}`change to Frech, if useValue:'es' in Spanish... It is what are you looking for?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `{provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr'}` as Eliseo said